# Update Field with FieldPath, update doesn't accept FieldPath as parameter - Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to delete a FieldValue inside Firebase, but the key had a "/" in it.
So my app gave me this exception:

```
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/unknown] Use FieldPath.of() for field names containing '~*/[]'.)
```

After researching "FieldPath" for a while, I came up with following:

```
final CollectionReference userTodos = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');
Future deleteToDo(String key, String listID) async {
    return await userTodos
        .doc(userID)
        .collection('Lists')
        .doc(listID)
        .update(FieldPath([key]), FieldValue.delete());
  }
```

But for some reason, it gives me this error:

```
The argument type 'FieldPath' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, Object?>'
```

I don't understand why because here it says it accepts a String or FieldPath:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update

Could someone help me please?
Thanks :)

Comment: Is it a top-level field? can you share what the structure of the document is in Firebase? I believe your keys should be clean and without special characters to begin with to avoid these issues. Let us know so we can provide some assistance.

Comment: Yes it is a top level field. In that document are just boolean values. Problem is, that I wan't the User to be able to input special characters as key.

Comment: Can you share for example what special characters are the ones you want to use as keys? as long as they are escaped strings i believe you are good

Comment: I'm pretty sure if your fields are a top-level field, are strings and correctly escaped, you should be able to do **update({ key : FieldValue.delete()})** with no problem, without using the **FieldPath** with the array syntax since that syntax is more for "nested fields"

Comment: @RomanJaquez Thanks. I did end up with checking for special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the documentation of the JavaScript Firestore client API, while you are using the Dart programming language. That's the source of confusion.

The Dart Firestore client's [`DocumentReference.update` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/update.html) doesn't accept `FieldPath`s.